# Python using beautiful soup to extract attribute from html

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use the `BeautifulSoup` library in Python to extract the jpg image names from a html script. In the url wherever you find `srcset` it is always proceeded by a jpg file name. I want to extract all the jpg files this way however whenever I run the following code it prints out `None`. However in the url there is always a jpg file name after srcset. For example , ' `srcset="https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/31/94/3194ec1ca5e3a56cb83f708533b9084d_best.jpg"` ' can be found in the html.

```
import urllib2 
html = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.shopstyle.com/p/prada-notch-lapel-fitted-blazer/645742403").read()

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print soup.find(attrs= {"img":"srcset"})
```

Comment: Can you give the entire tag where the Image can be found?

Comment: Hope it helps
soup.find('img', attrs = {'srcset' : True})

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find all urls from `srcset` you can do this:

```
import urllib2 
html = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.shopstyle.com/p/prada-notch-lapel-fitted-blazer/645742403").read()

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for el in soup.findAll('img', attrs = {'srcset' : True}):
    print el['srcset']
```

Your query returns `None` because argument `attrs` expected a dictionary with a property as key and filter as value. See the explanation from [bs4 docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attrs)

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
soup.find('img')['srcset']
'https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/31/94/3194ec1ca5e3a56cb83f708533b9084d_best.jpg'
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to extract all the jpg files

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_doc = requests.get("https://www.shopstyle.com/p/prada-notch-lapel-fitted-blazer/645742403")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc.content, 'html.parser')
imgs = [i.get('srcset') for i in soup.find_all('img', srcset=True)]

print(imgs)
```

The output:

```
['https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/31/94/3194ec1ca5e3a56cb83f708533b9084d_best.jpg', 'https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/16/c3/16c3e46d3547d6404ba29b61b8f229fd_best.jpg', 'https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/65/e6/65e6d0e3c0160f0aca361934b999f0c9_best.jpg', 'https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/sim/31/94/3194ec1ca5e3a56cb83f708533b9084d/prada-notch-lapel-fitted-blazer.jpg', 'https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/sim/16/c3/16c3e46d3547d6404ba29b61b8f229fd/prada-notch-lapel-fitted-blazer.jpg', 'https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/sim/65/e6/65e6d0e3c0160f0aca361934b999f0c9/prada-notch-lapel-fitted-blazer.jpg', 'https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/73/76/737689fa284d6640f7619e5f2f3558a5_xlarge.jpg', 'https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/2c/b0/2cb0acb147bd20df78bc482d66d7218b_xlarge.jpg', 'https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/5c/20/5c20824543749df684f3264c5e976e8c_xlarge.jpg', 'https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/48/b8/48b81f60d61e5c23cdfa343940e43ce9_xlarge.jpg', 'https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/ff/08/ff081818581b0363d4c0ec02c2cba5d4_xlarge.jpg', 'https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/86/0a/860ae7abdde0bf40046d53668abbe126_xlarge.jpg', 'https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/2f/5c/2f5c78d017052b14fd2db0d886a2a326_xlarge.jpg', 'https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/49/d5/49d5de5b62e6ddc0864afee987dd5e67_xlarge.jpg', 'https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/50/04/5004bf25e97ac0e4564d8a219a3b34b4_xlarge.jpg', 'https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/a8/76/a876ac6696e140f34e4cf82b5dbcaadf_xlarge.jpg']
```